# Use controller result from other mvc project within solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I've got a new solution that contains several project 'groups'. Each group contains a Cloud Project, a Web Role Project and a Test Project. All Web Role Projects are MVC4.

One of the Web Roles is the entry point for the visitor. Parts of what the visitor will see, should come from the other Web Roles from within the solution. I cannot get it working and after spending several hours googling, I still cannot solve it. Maybe anyone can be helpful on this issue.

For example, I need to fill the header content with data that I can get from one of the other Web Roles. Let's call that controller `HeaderController`. The controller in the main project (`HomeController`) looks like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";


        //var headerController = new Generic.HeaderFooterContainer.Controllers.HeaderController();
        //var foo = headerController.Index().ExecuteResult();
        //ViewBag.Header = headerController.;

        return View();
    }
```

In the comments are some things I've tried to debug some things.

Here's the page layout of the main project. The body is still empty, as this problem is just about the page header which could be placed as html from the ViewBag or ViewData or even with an own @section.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="headerHolder">
            <div class="innertube">
                <div id="header">
                    @ViewBag.Header
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contentHolder">
            <div class="innertube">
                <div id="content">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footerHolder">
            <div class="innertube">
                <div id="footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bms")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem I face is that I just can't find out how I should make this work. How do I get the data in the header? A few things I've noticed are:

1. If I run the HeaderFooterContainer project in its dedicated solution, it works alright (I can get /Header and get the expected response displayed in the browser window)
2. If I run the Main project, I can see the home page, but if I ask for /Header, it can find the controller, but not the view. It's probably looking for the view in the main project although it is located in the HeaderFooterContainer project.

Comment: What are your trying to accomplish? It feels like you should be looking into/using areas instead. Now each project represents a webpage you will be hosting. How can one controller form webpage A access a view/layout from webpage B, or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: It's all going to be hosted in Windows Azure and there'll be more websites that are going to use the same sources like the header/footer, the layout, and other common things. It's going to be a very large system so we want to be able to do maintenance one one aspect of the system without having downtime on the whole thing. The latter wouldn't be acceptable as governments would be responsible for loss of money and in the worst case even loss of life that could happen due to a major system downtime. The helper projects like HeaderFooterContainer don't necessarily have to be a webpage though.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if that is your argument for your design you maybe need to read up a little more. I mean, one of the features of Azure is the [staging](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/staging-deployment/).

Comment: I know about staging; I'm sorry that my question isn't clear enough. I'll talk about this issue with my colleagues.